# grouped and alternating conditional formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have 3 sites, each of them have worked some tickets that I am reviewing. I would like to alternate between 2 shades of one color for each group: Site 1 would alternate between a lighter and a darker green, Site 2 would alternate between two shades of red, and Site 3 the same with Blue. However, I do not want to alternate every row, but rather every other ticket. The tickets may have a variable number of rows that are grouped with it.  See screenshot where i have manually applied an example of the formatting im going for (these are not the final colors, these are used because the originals werent viewable after the image was uploaded).

Here is an image with the sample formatting:

[image]
Im fairly certain a helper column will be required here and while i'm fairly decent with excel and conditional formatting this one is a bit beyond me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. So, exactly, which one is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will only use the `Site` column and `Ticket` column from your example to demonstrate my solution. Suppose the `Site` column is in `Column A` and `Ticket` column is in `Column B`, I will use `Column C` as the helper column in the following way presume the first row is for headers that do not need to be formatted:

1. In cell `C2` enter number `1`, this value is hard-coded/static;
2. In cell `C3` enter the following formula and drag it down to the end of your table:

   `=MOD(IF(LEN($B3)=0,$C2,IF($B3=$B2,$C2,$C2+1)),2)`

Then you should have a helper column showing either `1` or `0` based on the ticket number.

Highlight your table with cell `A1` (i.e. the first cell of the range excluding header) being the active cell, set up the following conditional formatting rules one by one:

```
| Conditional Formatting Rules: | Format      |
|-------------------------------|-------------|
| =(MAX($A$2:$A2)*10+$C2)=11    | Light Green |
| =(MAX($A$2:$A2)*10+$C2)=10    | Dark Green  |
| =(MAX($A$2:$A2)*10+$C2)=21    | Light Red   |
| =(MAX($A$2:$A2)*10+$C2)=20    | Dard Red    |
| =(MAX($A$2:$A2)*10+$C2)=31    | Light Blue  |
| =(MAX($A$2:$A2)*10+$C2)=30    | Dark Blue   |
```

Then you should have the following:

[image: Demo]

> Please note Column D `Rule` is for demonstration only which is not necessary in the actual table. It shows you how my formulas have differentiated each row based on `Site` and `Ticket`.

**EDIT #2**

Given that the `Site` ID are actually texts rather than numbers, here is an alternative approach, which is still using the helper column as illustrated in the original solution, but the conditional formatting rules will be changed to:

```
| Conditional Formatting Rules:                                                               | Format      |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------|
| =(INDEX($A$2:$A2,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($A$1:$A1)/ISTEXT($A$2:$A2),1))&"#"&$C2)="Site Name 1#1" | Light Green |
| =(INDEX($A$2:$A2,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($A$1:$A1)/ISTEXT($A$2:$A2),1))&"#"&$C2)="Site Name 1#0" | Dark Green  |
| =(INDEX($A$2:$A2,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($A$1:$A1)/ISTEXT($A$2:$A2),1))&"#"&$C2)="Site Name 2#1" | Light Red   |
| =(INDEX($A$2:$A2,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($A$1:$A1)/ISTEXT($A$2:$A2),1))&"#"&$C2)="Site Name 2#0" | Dard Red    |
| =(INDEX($A$2:$A2,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($A$1:$A1)/ISTEXT($A$2:$A2),1))&"#"&$C2)="Site Name 3#1" | Light Blue  |
| =(INDEX($A$2:$A2,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW($A$1:$A1)/ISTEXT($A$2:$A2),1))&"#"&$C2)="Site Name 3#0" | Dark Blue   |
```

Here is the screen-shot:

[image: Demo2.0]

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201325/discussion-on-answer-by-terry-w-grouped-and-alternating-conditional-formatting).